# How to create .txt file on solution opening event of visual studio 2015?

Tags: c#

When we open the visual studio 2015 and select the solution or click on it the .txt file should get create automatically in some given location

Answer (score 1):

You can create an extension for visual studio 2015. Then subscribe to when solution is opened

```
_solutionEvents = _applicationObject.Events.SolutionEvents;
_solutionEvents.Opened += new SolutionHandler(SolutionOpened);
```

and in that method create a new text file with

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileFullPathAndName, text);
```